# nginx secure link sometimes return 403 error

Tags: php, nginx, mp4

In the logs of my server I often find a 403 error when a user accesses mp4 files, links to which are hidden using a secure link in nginx.
Most users do not face such difficulties. But only a few ...

nginx conf:

```
    server {
if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
}
        listen 80;
        server_name something.su www.something.su;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    }

server{

server_name_in_redirect off;
        if ($http_user_agent ~ Opera/9.12|facebook|80legs|360Spider|Aboundex|Abonti|Acunetix|^AIBOT|^Alexibot|Alligator|AllSubmitter|Apexoo|^asterias|^attach|^BackDoorBot|^BackStreet|^BackWeb|Badass|Bandit|Baid|Baiduspider|^BatchFTP|^Bigfoot|^Black.Hole|^BlackWidow|BlackWidow|^BlowFish|Blow|^BotALot|Buddy|^BuiltBotTough|^Bullseye|^BunnySlippers|BBBike|^Cegbfeieh|^CheeseBot|^CherryPicker|^ChinaClaw|^Cogentbot|CPython|Collector|cognitiveseo|Copier|^CopyRightCheck|^cosmos|^Crescent|CSHttp|^Custo|^Demon|^Devil|^DISCo|^DIIbot|discobot|^DittoSpyder|Download.Demon|Download.Devil|Download.Wonder|^dragonfly|^Drip|^eCatch|^EasyDL|^ebingbong|^EirGrabber|^EmailCollector|^EmailSiphon|^EmailWolf|^EroCrawler|^Exabot|^Express|Extractor|^EyeNetIE|FHscan|^FHscan|^flunky|^Foobot|^FrontPage|GalaxyBot|^gotit|Grabber|^GrabNet|^Grafula|^Harvest|^HEADMasterSEO|^hloader|^HMView|^HTTrack|httrack|HTTrack|htmlparser|^humanlinks|^IlseBot|Image.Stripper|Sucker|imagefetch|^InfoNaviRobot|^InfoTekies|^Intelliseek|^InterGET|^Iria|^Jakarta|^JennyBot|^JetCar|JikeSpider|^JOC|^JustView|^Jyxobot|^Kenjin.Spider|^Keyword.Density|libwww|^larbin|LeechFTP|LeechGet|^LexiBot|^lftp|^libWeb|^likse|^LinkextractorPro|^LinkScan|^LNSpiderguy|^LinkWalker|msnbot|MSIECrawler|MJ12bot|MegaIndex|^Magnet|^Mag-Net|^MarkWatch|Mass.Downloader|masscan|^Mata.Hari|^Memo|^MIIxpc|^NAMEPROTECT|^Navroad|^NearSite|^NetAnts|^Netcraft|^NetMechanic|^NetSpider|^NetZIP|^NextGenSearchBot|^NICErsPRO|^niki-bot|^NimbleCrawler|^Ninja|^Nmap|nmap|^NPbot|Offline.Explorer|Offline.Navigator|OpenLinkProfiler|^Octopus|^Openfind|^OutfoxBot|Pixray|probethenet|proximic|^PageGrabber|^pavuk|^pcBrowser|^Pockey|^ProPowerBot|^ProWebWalker|^psbot|^Pump|python-requests|^QueryN.Metasearch|^RealDownload|Reaper|^Reaper|^Ripper|Ripper|Recorder|^ReGet|^RepoMonkey|^RMA|scanbot|seoscanners|^Stripper|^Sucker|Siphon|Siteimprove|^SiteSnagger|SiteSucker|^SlySearch|^SmartDownload|^Snake|^Snapbot|^Snoopy|Sosospider|^sogou|spbot|^SpaceBison|^spanner|^SpankBot|Spinn3r|^Sqworm|Sqworm|Stripper|Sucker|^SuperBot|SuperHTTP|^SuperHTTP|^Surfbot|^suzuran|^Szukacz|^tAkeOut|^Teleport|^Telesoft|^TurnitinBot|^The.Intraformant|^TheNomad|^TightTwatBot|^Titan|^True_Robot|^turingos|^URLy.Warning|^Vacuum|^VCI|VidibleScraper|^VoidEYE|^WebAuto|^WebBandit|^WebCopier|^WebEnhancer|^WebFetch|^Web.Image.Collector|^WebLeacher|^WebmasterWorldForumBot|WebPix|^WebReaper|^WebSauger|Website.eXtractor|^Webster|WebShag|^WebStripper|WebSucker|^WebWhacker|^WebZIP|Whack|Whacker|^Widow|Widow|WinHTTrack|^WISENutbot|WWWOFFLE|^WWWOFFLE|^WWW-Collector-E|^Xaldon|^Xenu|^Zade|^Zeus|ZmEu|^Zyborg|SemrushBot|^WebFuck|^MJ12bot|^majestic12|^WallpapersHD|SputnikBot|Crowsnest|PaperLiBot|peerindex|ia_archiver|Slurp|Aport|NING|JS-Kit|rogerbot|BLEXBot|Twiceler|Java|CommentReader|Yeti|BTWebClient|Tagoobot|Ezooms|igdeSpyder|AhrefsBot|Offline|DISCo|netvampire|^Copier|omgili|socialmediascanner|Jooblebot|SeznamBot|Scrapy|CCBot|linkfluence|veoozbot|Leikibot|Seopult|Faraday|hybrid|Go-http-client|SMUrlExpander|SNAPSHOT|getintent|ltx71|Nuzzel|SMTBot|Laserlikebot|facebookexternalhit|mfibot|OptimizationCrawler|crazy|Dispatch|ubermetrics|^HTMLParser|musobot|filterdb|InfoSeek|omgilibot|DomainSigma|SafeSearch|meanpathbot|statdom|spredbot|StatOnlineRuBot|openstat|DeuSu|semantic|postano|Embedly|NewShareCounts|linkdexbot|GrapeshotCrawler|Digincore|NetSeer|help.jp|getprismatic|Ahrefs|ApacheBench|Applebot|archive|BaiduBot|Birubot|bsalsa|Butterfly|Buzzbot|BuzzSumo|CamontSpider|curl|dataminr|DomainTools|DotBot|FairShare|FeedFetcher|FlaxCrawler|FlightDeckReportsBot|FlipboardProxy|FyberSpider|Gigabot|gold\ crawler|InternetSeer|Jakarta|km.ru|kmSearchBot|Kraken|larbin|Lightspeedsystems|Linguee|LinkBot) {
            return 423;
        }


        if ($http_user_agent ~ LinkExchanger|bingbot|msnbot|LinkpadBot|LivelapBot|LoadImpactPageAnalyzer|majestic|Mediatoolkitbot|MetaURI|MLBot|NerdByNature|NjuiceBot|Nutch|OpenHoseBot|Panopta|pflab|PHP/|pirst|PostRank|ptd-crawler|Purebot|PycURL|Python|QuerySeekerSpider|Ruby|SearchBot|SISTRIX|SiteBot|Sogou|solomono|Soup|suggybot|Superfeedr|SurveyBot|SWeb|trendictionbot|TSearcher|ttCrawler|TurnitinBot|TweetmemeBot|UnwindFetchor|urllib|uTorrent|Voyager|WBSearchBot|Wget|WordPress|woriobot|YottosBot|Zeus|zitebot|bingot|mail.ru|tut.by|Br.by|Zubr.com|All.by|Tit.by|21.by|Rambler|Lycos|nigma.ru|Yahoo|alexa.com|archiver|LiveInternet|BegunAdvertising|vkShare|WebArtexBot|Web-Monitoring|Runet-Research-Crawler|SputnikFaviconBot|CNCat|Virusdie|YoudaoBot|WorldSearch|Wotbox|securepoint|Facebot|AltaVista|Custo|Demon|eCatch|WebWhacker|Express|WebPictures|ExtractorPro|FlashGet|GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|rafula|Stripper|Indy|Spider|Vampire|Foto|WebSpider|WebGo|Quester|Twengabot|perl|scan|email|Pyth|PyQ|WebCollector|WebCopy|webcraw|AcoonBot|adbeat_bot|AddThis.com|adidxbot|ADmantX|ExpertSearch|ExpertSearchSpider|extract|F2S|FastSeek|feedfinder|FeedlyBot|finbot|Flamingo_SearchEngine|FlappyBot|flicky|Flipboard|g00g1e|genieo|Genieo|GigablastOpenSource|GozaikBot|grab|GT::WWW|GTB5|Guzzle|harvest|heritrix|HomePageBot|HTTP::Lite|HubSpot|icarus6|id-search|IDBot|IlseBot|Indigonet|integromedb|IRLbot|ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2.1|JobdiggerSpider|JOC\ Web\ Spider|Jorgee|kanagawa|KINGSpider|kmccrew|mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com|AngloINFO|Antelope|BeetleBot|billigerbot|binlar|bitlybot|BLP_bbot|BoardReader|Bolt\ 0|BOT\ for\ JCE|Bot\ casper|CazoodleBot|checkprivacy|chromeframe|Clerkbot|Cliqzbot|clshttp|DTS.Agent|EasouSpider|ecxi|Elmer|ExaleadCloudView|CommonCrawler|comodo|crawler4j|Crawlera|CRAZYWEBCRAWLER|Curious|CWS_proxy|Default\ Browser\ 0|diavol|DigExt|DoCoMo|DotBot|Baidu) {
            return 423;
        }

#set $no_cache 1;


location ~* ^/(composer.phar) {
    deny all;
}

location = /status-inverser {
    stub_status;
}

location ~* ^/(vendor)($|\/) {deny all;}
expires $expires;
### include google-analytics.conf;
#       location / {
#           post_action @GAlog;
#       }
#location = /404.html {
#   post_action @GAlog404;
#}


if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){return 444;}
        server_tokens off;
        #listen  80;
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;

        ssl_certificate    /etc/crt/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/crt/private.key;
        server_name something.su www.something.su;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 1h;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains" always;
        http2_push_preload on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/crt/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

root /var/www/html/something.su;
charset utf8;

location ~ \.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    access_log off;
    expires 365d;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|docx|doc|rtf|js|ttf|otf|woff2|eot|svg|woff)$ {
access_log off;
expires 365d;
}
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|txt|docx|doc|js)$ {
valid_referers none blocked
               something.su www.something.su;

if ($invalid_referer) {
   rewrite   ^/   https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
}
}


location ~ \.mp4$ 
{

aio threads;

valid_referers none blocked
               something.su www.something.su;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
       rewrite   ^/   https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
    }
      mp4;
secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr secure_word";
if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }

      if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
    {
    set $filename $1;
    add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename";
    }
}

location ~ \.flv$ 
{valid_referers none blocked
               something.su www.something.su;

if ($invalid_referer) {
   rewrite   ^/   https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
}
  flv;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    index index.php;
}

#rewrite ^/index.php?page=(.*) /$1 permanent;
location ~ /(.*) {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$1;


   }

location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php index.php;
}

location @missing {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/index.php permanent;
}


error_page  404  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
error_page  403  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status&ra=$remote_addr;
error_page  405  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
error_page  415  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
error_page  401  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
error_page  402  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;
error_page  500  https://something.su/errorvps?rq=$request&rf=$http_referer&st=$status;






}
##SERVER
```

PHP code:

```
function bsl($path){
    $expires = time() + 36000;//10h
    $userIp = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    $p_ = stripos($userIp, ',');
    if ($p_ !== false) {
        $userIp=explode(',',$userIp);
        $userIp=trim($userIp[0]);
    }
    $secret = 'secure_word';
    $path = str_replace('https://something.su', '', $path);
    $md5 = md5("$expires$path$userIp $secret", true);
    $md5 = base64_encode($md5);
    $md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_');
    $md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
    return  "https://something.su{$path}?md5={$md5}&expires={$expires}";
}
```

Error log and useragents:

```
2020-01-21 10:28:16 | IP: 109.110.90.50 | Br: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; ru-ru; Redmi 7A Build/PKQ1.190319.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/11.3.4-g
403 |REF: https://something.su/download-446-f-6 | RQF: GET /file.mp4?md5=hQXVx4a2wbIBOtIMAGhWYA

2020-01-21 10:44:06 | IP: 62.182.94.xx | Br: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; ru-ru; Redmi Note 5 Build/OPM1.171019.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/11.3.4-g
403 |REF: https://something.su/download-35-f-1 | RQF: GET /file.mp4 HTTP/1.1

2020-01-21 10:45:41 | IP: 84.54.114.xx, 185.26.180.xx | Br: Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/18.0.2254/163.76; U; ru) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16
403 |REF: https://something.su/download-435-f-1 | RQF: GET /file.mp4?md5=djyUqY5N3btlfQYVs9NKwA

2020-01-21 10:44:03 | IP: 213.87.120.xx | Br: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; arm; Android 6.0.1; SM-G532F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.6.88.00 Mobile Safari/537.36
403 |REF: https://something.su/download-iNwdq oFH3bp62pRkgR52xLaqbTjz JElOn2tX7JXPDEvoV6Xa0Ti3I08PonyGLD7M3gJvriVj5TF2e3l5BzUw== | RQF: GET /file.mp4 HTTP/2.0
```

**&expires=1235478..** works in a full link, but is not in log file...

For a secure link, I set the time to 10 hours of life.
There is a possibility that in older browsers the page simply does not refresh, but loads as is, if, for example, the user accesses it after 10 hours of inactivity.
But something tells me that there is a catch and something needs to be fixed ...

Answer (score 0):

in function **bsl** I did not pass IP correctly IP...

```
$ip='';    
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```